# cucumber and cheese unable to run puppies app locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, page-object-gem

Running through Jeff Morgan: Cucumber and Cheese, all working until I get to CH6 database.
went to cheezyworld, downloaded and unzipped app.

```
8300:~/cheezy2/puppies$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching version metadata from http://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Could not find addressable-2.3.1 in any of the sources
```

I searched and got past the addressable-2.3.1 error with another version, but that led to more problems. My next step was to goto github to get the latest puppies app github cheezy puppies, I have tried both downloading the zip and cloning.

My Environment: (Note, I am just beginning with Ruby et al)

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Rubymine IDE, though, this is a command line issue
- /home/userid/.rvm/gems shows ruby-1.9.3.p194, ruby-2.0.0-p643, ruby-2.1.2 and ruby-2.2.2

Questions:

1. Should I be using the github lastest version or the cheezyworld
   version?
2. What action(s) should I take to get the puppies app running locally and resolve the  Error: Could not find table puppies
3. What do I do to get past all the rvm errors and/or warnings?

Thanks - details follow below

After unzipping the dir and cd'ing to it I get:

```
8300:~/cheezy$ cd puppies
You are using '.rvmrc', it requires trusting, it is slower and it is not 
compatible with other ruby managers,
you can switch to '.ruby-version' using 'rvm rvmrc to ruby-version'
or ignore this warning with 
'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /home/user/cheezy/puppies/.rvmrc',
'.rvmrc' will continue to be the default project 
file in RVM 1 and RVM 2,
to ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning 
ignore all.rvmrcs'.
```

I searched and found I should do this:

```
8300:~/cheezy/puppies$ rvm rvmrc warning ignore all.rvmrcs
8300:~/cheezy/puppies$ bundle install
```

I then do  rails s

```
8300:~/cheezy/puppies$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.11 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2015-09-17 14:31:26] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-09-17 14:31:26] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2012-04-20) [x86_64-linux]
[2015-09-17 14:31:26] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=26994 port=3000
```

According to the book, the above is correct. However, when I goto the url
    localhost:3000

I see error at the console:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-17 14:31:59 -0700
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Processing by AgencyController#index as HTML
  Rendered agency/index.html.erb within layouts/application (19.8ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 43ms

ActionView::Template::Error (Could not find table 'puppies'):
    4: 
    5: <h1>Puppy List</h1>
    6: 
    7: <% @puppies.each do |puppy| -%>
    8:   <div class="puppy_list">
    9:     <div class='<%= cycle('list_line_odd', 'list_line_even') %>'>
    10:       <div class="image"><%= image_tag(puppy.image_url, :class => 'list_image') %></div>
  app/views/agency/index.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_agency_index_html_erb___380271329036758088_31446620'


  Rendered /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (5.6ms)
```

At the browser I get an error page

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Agency#index
Showing /home/user/cheezy/puppies/app/views/agency/index.html.erb where line #7 raised:
Could not find table 'puppies'
```

I ran rvm list:

```
:~/.rvm/gems$ rvm list
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/home/userid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin' is not at first place,
     usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
     it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
     to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.2.2'.

rvm rubies

   ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p643 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.2 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.2.1 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.2.2 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Comment: I'm  a ruby-rookie, I googled "ruby migrations" and I see it has to do with the DB tables. I'm not sure what I should be migrating to. Can you be more specific - please?

Comment: @BradWerth - thanks, my bad! Failure to read the entire project ReadMe which was specifically updated 2 years ago to cover this issue. I was downloading from github but reading the instructions as shown in the book. I will add an answer for the next guy

Answer (score 1):

If you are following the Cucumber and Cheese Book:

- goto  [github puppies](https://github.com/cheezy/puppies) and clone the project
- when you cd to the puppies dir, you may see a warning regarding "trusting", run the command: rvm rvmrc trust ~/your-path/puppies/
- you may want to run: rvm list  # to ck ruby version for project
- you can run: cat .rvmrc        # to see what version the project requires
- insure the ruby version in .rvmrc matches the "current" version from rvm list
- read the entire README, for the most up-to-date instructions, e.g. rake db:seed, rake db:migrate, follow these before you run: rails s

Comment: How to fix this in windows, as RVM doesnt workon windows?